# Can I use a semicolon to add more information at the end of a sentence?

Tags: punctuation

I have a question on whether semicolons can be used to add information at the end of a sentence, something like this:

"This year, the university decided to deliver all courses online; rendering senior lecturers worried, since they are not quite adept with distance learning technology."

I'm also not sure whether "rendering senior lecturers worried...." is an independent clause.

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: That is precisely what the semicolon is for. [As Lewis Thomas put it](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/punctuation.html), "The semicolon tells you that there is still some question about the preceding full sentence; something needs to be added ... The period tells you that that is that; if you didn't get all the meaning you wanted or expected, anyway you got all the writer intended to parcel out and now you have to move along. But with a semicolon there you get a pleasant little feeling of expectancy; there is more to come; to read on; it will get clearer."

Comment: Loath as I am to disagree with @JohnLawler, the purpose of a semicolon is as stated in your headline, but in the example I would use a comma.

Comment: *Rendering …* is ***not*** an independent clause, so the use of the semicolon is incorrect in this case. Although sentence fragments can be stylistically acceptable, I've yet to see a semicolon used with one. If all I did was replace the punctuation mark, I would use a dash, colon, or comma instead.

Comment: Oh, I thought _rendering senior lecturers_ was another British academic title, like _senior wrangler_. Preparing seniors for consumption is apparently a big deal in the UK.

Comment: @JohnLawler "senior lecturers" might be a title, but "rendering" is not part of it. The meaning is "This rendered senior lecturers worried, ..."

Comment: I am fond of following the semicolon (or comma) with a dash;— a device much (over?) used in _The Life & Opinions of Tristram Shandy, Gentleman_ (1760). Here's an example of Sterne's style:  _Horace_, I know, does not recommend this fashion altogether: But that gentleman is speaking only of an epic poem or a tragedy;—(I forget which)—besides, if it were not so, I should beg Mr. _Horace's_ pardon;— for in writing what I have set about, I shall confine myself neither to his rules, nor to any man's rules that ever lived.

Answer (score 2):

As Jim Mack and Jason Bassford wrote, **the purpose of the semicolon as stated in your headline is correct; however, your specific usage of the semicolon is incorrect.**  I purposefully put a bunch of semicolons in my response (so you can see some examples of them in use), so keep an eye out for them; in fact, there is one right here.

A well-written page about semicolons can be found [HERE](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/semicolon.html).  The use of a semicolon in your case would likely be to link two independent clauses (as you implicitly stated in your question).

The issue with your sentence is that the part after the semicolon (quoted below) isn't an independent clause.

> ...rendering senior lecturers worried, since they are not quite adept with distance learning technology.

**An independent clause, when isolated, can be a sentence.**  **Note:** even though a clause might be unintelligible once isolated (due to a lack of context), it is still an independent clause if it is a full sentence.

Here is an example sentence with two independent clauses separated by a semicolon: **"Most kids eat lunch in the cafeteria; I prefer the gym."**

Let's break it down.  If we isolate the segment before the semicolon, we get: "Most kids eat lunch in the cafeteria."  This can stand alone as a sentence; therefore, it is an independent clause.  The second half is: "I prefer the gym." This can also stand alone as a sentence, so it is an independent clause as well.

Now, let's return to your sentence.  The first half is: "This year, the university decided to deliver all courses online."  This can stand alone as a sentence, so it is an independent clause.  The second half is: "Rendering senior lecturers worried, since they are not quite adept with distance learning technology."  Hopefully, you can see that **this is not a full sentence, and is therefore not an independent clause.**

There is one idea that really makes semicolons easier to understand (for me—hopefully for you as well).  Imagine you are studying for the English section of the SAT.  The question asks you which punctuation is correct in a given sentence.  One of the options is a period; another is a semicolon.  Automatically, neither of the two is correct.  Here's why: the SAT has to have an *objective* answer, and the decision between a period and a semicolon is completely *subjective*; it is the author's choice.

**Fundamentally, a semicolon (in this context) is a period, but it implies that the two halves of the sentence are closely related.**  This is why we can isolate the two clauses to see if they are independent clauses.  If you had chosen a period instead of a semicolon (both of which have the same syntactic function in this case), the clauses would have had to stand alone.  Therefore, they must be able to stand alone, even though you chose a semicolon.

**Note:** I didn't talk about what the components of an independent clause are.  If you want to learn about them, I recommend that you read [THIS](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/punctuation/independent_and_dependent_clauses/index.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! :D

Comment: @YohanesTheda I'm happy I could help! If my answer was satisfactory, mark it as correct so future readers know that my answer was accurate. Also, it will prevent others from wasting their time to write an answer for a question that is already resolved.